# Sendgrid SMTP is not working but CURL api is working fine

Tags: laravel, smtp, sendgrid

I am having following smtp .env regarding sendgrid in laravel and following https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/laravel/

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=apikey
MAIL_PASSWORD=myapi_key
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=fromemail@gmail.com
```

Did not work but when I make a CURL call like below working fine.

```
curl --request POST \                                                 
  --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer $apiKey" \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "myemail@gmail.com"}]}],"from": {"email": "fromemail@gmail.com", "name": "Product Name"},"subject": "Sending with SendGrid is Fun","content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "and easy to do anywhere, even with cURL"}]}'
```

Is there anything I need to make it workable.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing configuration cache by typing *php artisan cache:clear*